# How to use fonts in android embedded in another android application?

Tags: android

I have two android applications. The apks are Hello.apk and Fonts.apk

I would like to use the fonts that i store in fonts.apk to be used in Hello.apk

The reason is that i want to add newer fonts to an existing application so that whenever new fonts are required i just need to install newer fonts.apk. I have configuration in Hello.apk about which fonts to use.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is a ContentProvider: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
Then you would have Fonts.apk expose the ContentProvider, and Hello.apk use it

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have one apk which you download and it installs the fonts onto the sd card and the other apk reads them if they are present

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done anything with this type of stuff yet but in the future I will be, Ill see if I can find an example